# Test-NetConnection works but Test-WsMan indicates a network issue

Tags: powershell, remoting

When running a Test-NetConnection, I can see port 5985 connects ok from server A to B.

And doing a Test-WsMan from desktop C to server B, it works.

However a Test-WsMan from server A to B, does not work.

All machines are on different subnets, both server firewalls indicate a domain connection. And it appears the windows firewall is not on.

The WsMan error indicates it's a networking issue (I've replaced the domain name with an example name).

```
Test-WSMan : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859046"
Machine="1.example.org"><f:Message>WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified
computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM
service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles
limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. </f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:1
```

Most articles help diagnose firewall issues, but this does not appear to be one if the tcp connection works. I'm not sure what diagnostic techniques to try next to understand what the error could be.

Comment: just for testing, disable the firewall on the both and retest, if still then I belive something other is playing with you

Comment: but on the second, is there an issue?

Comment: Thanks @djdomi I've added some clarity. client A, should of really read desktop. It's a third machine used to test things out.

Comment: as it makes more complicated than before, did you disabled all firewalls on all windows computers? how do they connect to each other, through hub, switch, firewall, VPN?

Comment: Authentication issues often bubble up with this error.  If the receiving system can't authenticate the request it will drop the it without a response.  The result is this generic "something is wrong with the connection" error.  

This is separate from "Access Denied" which is commonly triggered by an unprivileged account vs an unauthenticated account.